The sum of $O_p$ --$ O_p \left(s^2\frac{\log d}{n}+s\sqrt{\frac{\log d}{n}} \right) $
I read papers in the area of inference for high-dimensional graphical models and these papers always state the convergence rate of the estimator. Using $O_p$ is a good choice.
Maybe I made some mistakes and I have some questions about the sum of $O_p$. I know that people often use the property $O_p(a_n)+O_p(b_n)=O_p(a_n+b_n)$. it’s slightly different.
For example, here, the proof of theorem B.4 in page 25 says that
$$
O_p\left(\sqrt{\frac{\log d}{n}}\right)+O_p\left(s^2(\log d/n)^{3/2}+s\frac{\log d}{n}\right)+O_p\left(s^2 \frac{\log d}{n}+s\sqrt{\frac{\log d}{n}}\right)=O_p\left(s^2(\log d/n)^{3/2}+s^2 \frac{\log d}{n}+s\sqrt{\frac{\log d}{n}}\right)
$$
where $s$ constrains the maximum degree of the graph and $d$ is the number of the features. This article has many similar situations. I don't know why these equations are correct and why the authors keep the two items related to $s^2$.
When the authors try to bound term (iii).b (page26), they get
$$
O_p\left(s^2\frac{\log d}{n}+s\sqrt{\frac{\log d}{n}}\right)
$$
the second term is the square root of the first term. Why can they appear at the same time? I mean, Why can't one of them control the other?
My question

why can we omit some terms in $O_p$?

$\frac{\log d}{n}$ stays constant or goes to infinity when discussing high-dimensional statistics.

$s$ represents the "true sparsity" parameter and stays constant or goes to infinity in the above situation. Does $s$ depend on $n$?



You can drop terms when you know they are smaller than some constant multiple of other terms. For example, because $s>1$, we know
$$s^2\frac{\log d}{n}>s\frac{\log d}{n}$$
which is why the second term in the second $O_p$ expression vanishes.
Conversely, if you don't know that one term is smaller than a constant multiple of another, you need to keep them both. If $s^2(\log d/n)\gg 1$ then $$s^2(\log d/n)>s\sqrt{\log d/n}$$
but if $s^2(\log d/n)\ll 1$ then
$$s^2(\log d/n)<s\sqrt{\log d/n}.$$
If you want a bound that works in both settings you need both terms.

I see, but in the first expression, there are three terms in $O_p$. Does this mean that we need to consider not only the situation you mentioned ($s^2(\log d/n)$) but also the convergence rate of  $\sqrt{\log d/n}$?
